# r prefix in python

Tags: python, string

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase 'n'. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

Source: [Python string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

This confused me because the `r` prefix only seems to work on the `n` as given in the example.

The code I was confused about:

```
import re
str= "One one two three"
result=re.findall(r'o\w\w',str)
print(result)
```

Doesn't having the `r` prefix at the beginning of the regex mean that the backslashes do not escape the letter `w`, giving it a special meaning (i.e.  alphanumeric character)?
the result is :['one']

Comment: The r means that the \w in the text is not changed so the regex will receive the string as written

Comment: The r isn't for regex. It's a **raw** string

Comment: why is it used in regex so commonly?

Comment: What happens when you try this code?

Comment: the example in the text above '\n' gives it as two characters the \ and the n but why isnt it the same when used in re.findall

Comment: isnt r'o\w\w' a match for the letter o, the backslash character, the w character, the backslash character and a w?

Comment: Why is it used in regex so so commonly? `'\b'` represents the backspace character, which is altogether different than the two-character sequence of a backslash followed by a `b`, `'\\b'`, which has very special meaning when used in regular expressions. But rather having to enter `'\\b'`, it is easier to enter `r'\b'`, which has the same effect. This is just one example. `r'\n'` would be another.

Comment: No, `\w` is a `special sequence` in a Python regular expression pattern - sometimes referred t as a shorthand character class. Raw strings are used as a convenience so you don't have to use double slashes to match a literal slash in a pattern.

Comment: In other words, raw character strings prevent the interpretation of special character sequences such as `\b` for backspace, `\n` for newline, `\a` for alarm, etc. For other characters, it doesn't matter whether you use a raw character string or not: `r'\d' == '\d'` (because `'\d' == '\\d'`)

Comment: To match `\w` using a raw string the pattern would be `r'\\w'` because `\w` is a special sequence.

Comment: @wwii: but only when used in a regex. Another common use of `r'string'` is with Windows path names: `r'c:\windows\temp'`. There neither `\w` nor `\t` mean anything, and must not be parsed in any way.